# Converting a user input word into a unicode array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, char, int, type-conversion

So I am having a problem figuring out how to convert a word that the user input into a int array that has each of the letters of the word in their own unicode values (so something like "A" would turn into 65 in the array). I was thinking of one way that this could be done is that first I have the word input by the user split up into separate chars (so the String "And" would first be split up into chars "A", "n", "d", and then would turn into ints 65, 110, 100 when they are put into the int array). The problem is that I am lost on where to go. I am not sure how I would split the word up into separate chars, and then have those chars be converted, and go into an int array. Any help is greatly appreciated! Also just as I side note I need to be able to find the maximum, minimum, and average of all the values as well.

Comment: Look at the `charAt()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void stringToArray (){                                  
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input String: ");             
        String input = in.nextLine();
        Integer[] lista = new Integer[input.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
            lista[i] = input.codePointAt(i);  
            System.out.print(lista[i] + " ");
        }        
        System.out.print("\nArray descending order: ");
        Arrays.sort(lista, Collections.reverseOrder());
        for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++) 
            System.out.print(lista[i] + " ");                                   
        if (lista.length>0) {  
            int min=lista[0];
            int max=lista[0];
            int sum=0;
            int avg;
            for(int i=0;i<lista.length;i++){
                if (lista[i]> max) max=lista[i];
                if (lista[i]< min) min=lista[i];
                sum += lista[i];                
            }
            avg=sum/lista.length;                
            System.out.println("\nThe maximun value is: "+max);
            System.out.println("The minimun value is: "+min);
            System.out.println("The average value is: "+avg);                            
        }
}
```

Comment: That helped, but I am still trying to figure out how to make it so I can just type in the word once instead of once for my method that figures out if it is a palindrome, and the method above that gets the word into an int array.

Comment: Would you know how to then sort the values from greatest to least when it shows the array, this is the last thing I need to do for now.

Comment: Modified: Sorting the array in descending order.
Change of type of array from int to Integer class to use `Arrays.sort (list, Collections.reverseOrder ());`

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Java and am a bit confused. I just need to order the number from least to greatest like they were when the array is displayed (so something like if it was 5 3 1 4 2 it would then become 1 2 3 4 5 instead).

Comment: Then you have to use `Arrays.sort (lista);` instead of: `Arrays.sort (lista, Collections.reverseOrder ());`

Comment: I have been trying that but then it makes always turns the lowest value into zero, which messes up the max, min, and avg.

Answer (score 0):

This will add each character to an integer array:

```
public static int[] codepoints(String str) {
    int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = str.charAt(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/exZToG)

Comment: Would this be able to take user input value? The answer above worked with a word that is hard coded in, but I need it to take the chars from the user input word, which are then converted into the ints in the in[].

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to iterate the characters in your `String` and copy them into a new `int` array like,

```
public static int[] getPoints(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int[] out = new int[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        out[i] = chars[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

And then you might test it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getPoints("And")));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
[65, 110, 100]
```

Comment: That would work but I need to have it so it takes the users input word, and not a word that was just hard coded in (I was just using "And" as an example).

Comment: @Fyree So, get the user input and then call `getPoints(String)` like my example.